# How to properly solidify a complex object?

Tags: solidify-modifier

I have this complex 3D object and I would like to fill it in using solidify.
My problem is that ever time I try to solidify the object, it takes odd shapes:

[image: screenshot showing odd shape]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Remove the bottom, solidify and create the bottom again. Select the whole bottom and solidify it.

Comment: it doesn't appear to work too well....the borders are solidified improperly

Comment: Please upload the blend file so that we can have a look. Instructions [here](https://blend-exchange.com/help).

Comment: Check if Normals are correct or for any double vertices